# Passing negative values for dimensions with PHP FFMpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I'm working on a legacy project that uses FFMpeg to process videos on upload. The code I inherited uses `escapeshellarg()` to run FFMpeg from the command line, which is problematic because it doesn't provide any means of keeping track of progress, so I'm rewriting it using [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg).

I'm a bit stumped at the point of resizing the videos. The aspect ratio needs to remain the same, so the dimensions passed to the command line for the scale were `-vf scale=-1:720`, and my interpretation of the documents is that you need to pass the dimensions through as follows:

```
$dimension = new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension('-1', '720');
$video->filters()->resize($dimension)->synchronize();
```

However, the constructor of the `Dimension` class only accepts integers, and it's unclear how I'd go about specifying a negative dimension here. Google hasn't been very useful, nor have the existing issues on the project.

Any idea how I could pass through the required dimensions? I don't often use FFMpeg so I'm not terribly familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out in the end. Turns out the second argument to `resize()` is the mode, which determines how to scale the two dimensions. If you set this to scale the width to fit the height, it should work as expected:

```
$dimension = new FFMpeg\Coordinate\Dimension('-1', '720');
$mode = FFMpeg\Filters\Video\ResizeFilter::RESIZEMODE_SCALE_HEIGHT;
$video->filters()->resize($dimension, $mode)->synchronize();
```